# Объединить два DataFrame по столбцу (аналог "INNER JOIN" в SQL)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Есть два DataFrame:

```
        art     
0  00000169    
1  00000225    
2  00000227    
3  00000300
```

И второй:

```
        art     set      pr
0  00000169     A        16.30
1  00000210     B        35.10
2  00000225     C        11.40
3  00000227     B        53.30
```

Нужно получить DataFrame из содержимого строк второго DataFrame по списку первого:

```
          art     set      pr
0  00000169     A        16.30
1  00000225     C        11.40
2  00000227     B        53.30
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) - для объединения двух таблиц по столбцам с одинаковыми именами:

```
res = df2.merge(df1)
```

результат:

```
In [7]: res
Out[7]:
        art set    pr
0  00000169   A  16.3
1  00000225   C  11.4
2  00000227   B  53.3
```

PS можно воспользоваться параметрами `left_on` и `right_on` если имена столбцов не совпадают

Comment: Спасибо! Жму руку.

Comment: @Матросик, чтобы поблагодарить авторов ответов можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814). PS принять ответ как правильный можно только один. Автор вопроса решает какой ответ отметить как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

По простому как-то так, если правильно помню:

```
df2.loc[df2.art.isin(df1.art)]
```

Ещё можно использовать `merge` и `join` практически как в `SQL`.